# Accessing Child nodes during Xml Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

How can I access the children of the Name element during Serialization?

```xml
<Person>
    <Name>
        <First>John</First>
        <Middle>Adam</Middle>
        <Last>Smith</Last>
        <Madian></Madian>
    </Name>
    <Gender>M</Gender>
</Person>
```

```cs
[XmlRootAttribute("Person", IsNullable= false)]
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name/First")]
    public string firstName;
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name/Middle", IsNullable = true)]
    public string middleName;
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name/Last")]
    public string lastName;
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name/Madian", IsNullable = true)]
    public string madianName;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Gender", DataType = "string")]
    public string gender;

    ...
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean *during Serialization*. What is the process surrounding the implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an intermediary class:

```
public class Name
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "First")]
    public string firstName;
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Middle", IsNullable = true)]
    public string middleName;
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Last")]
    public string lastName;
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Madian", IsNullable = true)]
    public string madianName;
}
```

and then use this class inside `Person`:

```
[XmlRootAttribute("Person", IsNullable= false)]
public class Person
{
    public Name Name;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Gender", DataType = "string")]
    public string gender;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    [XmlArray("Person")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Name", typeof(Name))]
    public List<Name> Name{ get; set; }
```

Comment: this does acutally answer the original question from my point of view.