# XmlSerializer access child logical elements in parent element

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I am using the standard .NET `XmlSerializer` to deserialize the following xml:

```
<root>
    <Element>
        <Grouping1>
            <Item1>First</Item1>
            <Item2>Second</Item2>
        </Grouping1>
        <Grouping2>
            <Item3>Third</Item3>
        </Grouping2>
    </Element>
</root>
```

I would like to serialize it into the following class:

```
class Element
{
    [XmlElement("Item1")]
    public string Item1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Item2")]
    public string Item2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Item3")]
    public string Item3 { get; set; }
}
```

Which of course doesn't work, because - for instance - `<Item1>` isn't located in `<Element>` but in the logical container `<Grouping1>`.

### The question:

Is there a way of telling the `XmlSerializer` to look for the `Item1` in the `<Grouping1>` element?
*Something downs the lines of `[XmlElement("Grouping1.Item1")]`*

---

*PS: I don't want to create a `Grouping1` class (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2254816/5757162)) because the groupings are only logical containers and shouldn't have their own class.*

Comment: You can use Xml Linq to create the class.  Serialization you would have to create a custom serialize.  Xml serialization requires a class or element for each unique tag name.  You have Grouping1 and Grouping2 which requires two classes.  You cannot with Xml serialization put children of Grouping1 and Grouping2 into one class.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the answer! My current solution is removing the `<Grouping1>` and `<Grouping2>` tags, which works fine until the `Grouping` elements have a child element with a common name. Do you have an idea on how overcome this issue?

Comment: Are you sure about the elements names? `Grouping1,2,3` and `Item1,2,3` ? Shouldn't be just `Grouping` and `Item` ?

Comment: @JQSOFT I don't quite get what you are after, but my problem might be a bit better visualized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2254792/5757162). `Grouping` 1 - n should just be a palce holder for a logic grouping (just like `Name` in the example above). Same goes with `Item` where they just reperesnt some arbritary name for a property.
Hope this helps to clarify

Answer (score 1):

Using Xml Linq.  A custom serializer would be much more complicated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Element> elements = doc.Descendants("Element").Select(x => new Element()
            {
                Item1 = (string)x.Descendants("Item1").FirstOrDefault(),
                Item2 = (string)x.Descendants("Item2").FirstOrDefault(),
                Item3 = (string)x.Descendants("Item3").FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();

         }
    }
    class Element
    {
        public string Item1 { get; set; }
        public string Item2 { get; set; }
        public string Item3 { get; set; }
    }


}
```

---

Here is what serializer would look like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            Root root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);


         }
    }
    [XmlRoot("root")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement("Element")]
        public List<Element> Element { get; set; }
    }

    public class Element : IXmlSerializable
    {
        private string Item1 { get; set; }
        private string Item2 { get; set; }
        private string Item3 { get; set; }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            XElement element = new XElement("Element", new object[] {
                new XElement("Grouping1", new object[] {
                    new XElement("Item1", Item1),
                    new XElement("Item2", Item2)
                }),
                new XElement("Grouping2", new XElement("Item3", Item3))
            });
            element.WriteTo(writer);

        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            XElement element = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);

            Item1 = (string)element.Descendants("Item1").FirstOrDefault();
            Item2 = (string)element.Descendants("Item2").FirstOrDefault();
            Item3 = (string)element.Descendants("Item3").FirstOrDefault();

        }

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return (null);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This is a viable solution for this small example scope, yes. Sadly enough my real-life-usecase utelizes 60+ Elements and it just insn't a practical solution to code that custom mapping for all of the Elements. 
Hence the request of using Attributes.

Comment: There are many ways of parsing xml and you have to look at the entire solution to pick best solution.  Xml Linq is nice because ti handles the non standard xml files and will give flatter results than standard zerialization.

Comment: I updated code to show what custom serialize would look like.

Answer (score 1):

> *I don't want to create a Grouping1 class...*

Not sure whether that's possible using serialization without creating the objects that output this XML.

An alternative to serialization is using the [XmlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=netcore-3.1) to *extract* the properties in question (`Item1`, `Item2`, and `Item3`) and create a list of `Element` type, and [XmlWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=netcore-3.1) to generate the whole XML file. Both classes provide fast, non-cached, and forward-only way to read and write XML files.

Assuming your XML file has multiple `Element` entries like:

```xml
<root>
  <Element>
    <Grouping1>
      <Item1>First1</Item1>
      <Item2>Second1</Item2>
    </Grouping1>
    <Grouping2>
      <Item3>Third1</Item3>
    </Grouping2>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <Grouping1>
      <Item1>First2</Item1>
      <Item2>Second2</Item2>
    </Grouping1>
    <Grouping2>
      <Item3>Third2</Item3>
    </Grouping2>
  </Element>
</root>
```

... and a class named `Element`:

```cs
//The serializable attribute is not required here...
public class Element
{
    public Element() { }

    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
    public string Item3 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"{Item1}, {Item2}, {Item3}";
}
```

Create a function to read the file, create and return a list of `Element` items:

```cs
public List<Element> ReadElements(string xmlFile)
{
    var elements = new List<Element>();
    Element ele = null;

    using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile))
        while (xr.Read())
        {
            if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (xr.Name == "Element")
                    ele = new Element();
                else if (xr.Name == "Item1")
                {
                    xr.Read();
                    ele.Item1 = xr.Value;
                }
                else if (xr.Name == "Item2")
                {
                    xr.Read();
                    ele.Item2 = xr.Value;
                }
                else if (xr.Name == "Item3")
                {
                    xr.Read();
                    ele.Item3 = xr.Value;
                }
            }
            else if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                if (xr.Name == "Element")
                    elements.Add(ele);
        }
    return elements;
}
```

... and a method to write:

```cs
public void WriteElements(string xmlFile, IEnumerable<Element> elements)
{
    var xmlSet = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true,
        NewLineOnAttributes = true,
        WriteEndDocumentOnClose = true,
    };

    using (var xr = XmlWriter.Create(xmlFile, xmlSet))
    {
        xr.WriteStartElement("root");                

        foreach(var ele in elements)
        {
            xr.WriteStartElement("Element");
            xr.WriteStartElement("Grouping1");
            xr.WriteStartElement("Item1");
            xr.WriteString(ele.Item1);
            xr.WriteEndElement();
            xr.WriteStartElement("Item2");
            xr.WriteString(ele.Item2);
            xr.WriteEndElement();
            xr.WriteEndElement();
            xr.WriteStartElement("Grouping2");
            xr.WriteStartElement("Item3");
            xr.WriteString(ele.Item3);
            xr.WriteEndElement();
            xr.WriteEndElement();
            xr.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }            
}
```

A test to read and write the file like:

```cs
private void TheCaller()
{
    var xmlFile = "XmlFile.xml";
    var elements = ReadElements(xmlFile);
    elements.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
    //...
    WriteElements(xmlFile, elements);
}
```

Prints in my output window:

```
First1, Second1, Third1
First2, Second2, Third2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
jdwengs solution was similar to this - to put it in one word: custommappig. 
As I've explained under his post as well, this isn't really a viable solution for my use case sadly enough :/

Comment: Thanks for the high qulity answer though!

Comment: @Squirrelintraining Most welcome buddy. As for the _logical Containers_ that you've mentioned in your post, that doesn't mean the grouping elements don't have a physical presence in the XML which means you should not ignore that and do something about it. Also if you could paste a real XML for a couple of Elements so we can dig better and maybe a better solution pops up.

Comment: Sorry, can't do that ^^'
But to have an Idea, imagine <Grouping1> having 70 Items (<Item1-Item70>).
And <Groupin2> Occasionally has mostly differene <Item>s and sometime an <Item> with the same name but not the same value.

Comment: @Squirrelintraining Now we have some better info to think which means both answers don't work for it. One last question to be on the same page. Do you have multiple `<Element>..</Element>`? and `Grouping3`, `Grouping4` ,...etc?

Comment: yes there exist multiple <element> which share a common set of <grouping>s each element has atleast <grouping1>  and can have the rest. Next to logical groupings there can also exist multiple <list>s with mutliple <listItem>s inside of them.